# Парсер lisp на lisp

Tags: компиляция, lisp, функциональное-программирование, racket

Здравствуйте! Решил написать компилятор [racket](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racket_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) (диалект lisp) на racket, для того, чтобы легко можно было проверить его полноценность (компилирует сам себя - все хорошо, нет - нужно пилить дальше). До этого писал компилятор для маленького lisp на с++, так что (примерно) представляю, что нужно делать.

Это первая большая программа на lisp, так что пока тяжело.

Например: вот такую простую функцию:

```
function ast(tokens, from, to)
{
  if(from == undefined)
    from = 0;

  if(to == undefined)
    to = tokens.length

  var ret = [];

  for(var i=from; i<to; i++)
  {
    if(tokens[i] == "(")
    {
      var level = 1;
      var start = i;
      while(level!=0)
      {
        i++;

        if(tokens[i] == "(")
            level++;

         if(tokens[i] == ")")
            level--;
      }

      ret.push(ast(tokens, start+1, i));
    }
    else
        ret.push(tokens[i])
  }

  return ret; 
}
```

Я попытался написать вот так (код страшный и нерабочий):

```
(define (parse tokens from to)
  (cond
    [(>= from to) '#()]
    [(not (and (vector-has tokens "(") (vector-has tokens ")"))) tokens]
     [else (let* [(fb (vector-index tokens "("))
                (lb (end tokens 1 (+ fb 1)))]
            (println (string-append "fb = " (number->string fb)))
            (println (string-append "lb = " (number->string lb)))

            (cond
              [(and (= fb 0) (= lb (- (vector-length tokens) 1))) (parse tokens (+ fb 1) (- lb 1))]
              [(= fb 0) (vector-append (parse tokens (+ fb 1) lb) (parse tokens (+ lb 1) (- (vector-length tokens) 1)))]
              [(= lb (- (vector-length tokens) 1)) (vector-append (parse tokens 0 (- fb 1)) (parse tokens (+ fb 1) (- (vector-length tokens) 1)))]
              [else (vector-append (parse tokens 0 (- fb 1)) (parse tokens (+ fb 1) (- lb 1)) (parse tokens (+ lb 1) (- (vector-length tokens) 1)))]
              )
            )]) )
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, переписать.